# WinInet - How to obtain server URL after 301 redirect?

Tags: c++, url, redirect, wininet

I'm programming with WinInet functions in C++ but I came across a problem.

My program opens an URL with `HttpOpenRequest()`, `HttpSendRequest()`, `InternetReadFile()`... functions and saves output data. I need to save URL with the output data, but in some cases server gives me `301 Moved` and `InternetReadFile()` reads file from the new address.

This is Ok, but I need to find out what address it is. I tried to use `HttpQueryInfo` with `HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF` but I didn't obtain this info, only `Content-Type`, `Cache-Control`, `Cookies`, etc. When I use `HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LOCATION` or something similar I get `ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND`.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After WinInet receives a Redirect response, by default it sends a new HTTP request to the new URL automatically.  By the time WinInet is ready for you to start reading file data with `InternetReadFile()`, the headers that are available at that time belong to the last URL requested, which may not be the same URL that you originally requested.  That is why you are not seeing see a `Location` header.  To process the headers for a Redirect response, you have to specify the `INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTO_REDIRECT` flag when calling `HttpOpenRequest()`, then you can use `HttpQueryInfo()` to detect a redirect status code and read its `Location` header before then calling `HttpSendRequest()` to request the new URL being redirected to.

Answer (score 1):

When a redirect happens automatically in wininet, you can get the redirect url by using a `InternetStatusCallback` function.  Code `INTERNET_STATUS_REDIRECT (110)` will supply a buffer with the new URL to the callback function. You can use `InternetSetStatusCallback()` on the `HINTERNET` handle to set a callback function for the request.

Comment: This is indeed a possible way, and is probably easier to handle than the accepted answer.